# Why can't I get my account info binance api

Tags: python, binance-api-client

*When I use the function `print(client.get_account())` this is my code followed by the output*

```py
from binance.client import Client,
import pandas as pd,
import mplfinance as mpl,
import numpy as np,
import os,
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, 
#I set up my credential for this api

api_key = '(my credential)' 

api_secret= '(my credential)'
client=Client(api_key,api_secret)

print(client.get_account())
```

*output*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\Mean_Reversion.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(client.get_account())
  File "C:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1956, in get_account
    return self._get('account', True, data=params)
  File "C:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 315, in _request
    return self._handle_response(self.response)
  File "C:\Users\berge\OneDrive\Documents\Binance Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 324, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1021): Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow.
```

Comment: You may consider formatting it as code.

Comment: Try looking in the binance documentation for the meaning of `APIError(code=-1021)`  (although I expect the meaning is according to the text "`Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow.`"

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem, and the solution is very simple. For the Binance API to work, your system time should be synced with the Binance time.

**Fix: In Windows, go to your Date & Time setting and click on "Sync now". Voila! fixed.**